# .htaccess and redirect urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have used the following to rewrite urls on my website

```
RewriteRule writers/(.*)/ writer-pages.php?page_name=$1
RewriteRule writers/(.*) writer-pages.php?page_name=$1
```

which works fine, but I have old pages that have an extension /writers/name-here.php and the rewrite above removes the .php how can I redirect the old .php to the the urls without the extension.

Another problem is I don't want redirect all .php pages

Any idea how I can do this. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule writers/(.*).php writers/$1/
```

you can test your rewrite rules at [rewrite-rule-tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: thanks for your reply hajlabajla but the for some reason the redirect wont work? any ideas why

Comment: Sorry my mistake I placed your code before my code and now works perfect. Thanks @hajlabajla

Answer (score 0):

- Your 2 rules can be combined into one.
- You need an additional rule.

Here is the code:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+writer-pages\.php\?page_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ writers/%1? [R=302,L]

# your original rule
RewriteRule writers/([^/]*)/?$ writer-pages.php?page_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```